# How to normalize within groups based on a value from a different column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Apologies for the inelegant title; I couldn't think of another way to say it. This is a problem I've encountered in a couple of different forms and can't find a satisfactory answer to.

Example: say I have been monitoring how many cups of tea and coffee I drink during the week:

```py
In [17]: import random
    ...: test = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'drink' : ['tea'] * 5 +  ['coffee'] * 5,
    ...:     'day' : ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'] * 2,
    ...:     'cups' : [random.randrange(1, 10)  for _ in range(10)]
    ...: })
    ...: test
    ...: 
    ...: 
Out[17]: 
    drink        day  cups
0     tea     monday     1
1     tea    tuesday     3
2     tea  wednesday     1
3     tea   thursday     7
4     tea     friday     1
5  coffee     monday     8
6  coffee    tuesday     1
7  coffee  wednesday     2
8  coffee   thursday     1
9  coffee     friday     1
```

In order to compare the amounts I would like to normalize them. I can easily normalize by dividing by the total for each day - this is pretty much the standard example of normalization with pandas:

```py
In [18]: test['day_norm'] = test.groupby('day')['cups'].transform(lambda x : x / 
    ...: x.sum())
In [19]: test
Out[19]: 
    drink        day  cups  day_norm
0     tea     monday     1  0.111111
1     tea    tuesday     3  0.750000
2     tea  wednesday     1  0.333333
3     tea   thursday     7  0.875000
4     tea     friday     1  0.500000
5  coffee     monday     8  0.888889
6  coffee    tuesday     1  0.250000
7  coffee  wednesday     2  0.666667
8  coffee   thursday     1  0.125000
9  coffee     friday     1  0.500000
```

But let's say instead I want to see how the values change over the week by dividing for each group by the value for monday - i.e. I want monday to be 1 and then every other day relative to that. I have managed to come up with two different ways of doing it, both of which seem convoluted.

One: I can write a function that filters the group dataframe to find monday's value then divides the series by it:

```py
In [20]: def normalize(df):
    ...:     monday_cups = df[df['day'] == 'monday']['cups'].mean()
    ...:     return df['cups'] / monday_cups
    ...: 
    ...: test['normalized cups'] = test.groupby('drink').apply(normalize).reset_i
    ...: ndex(level=0, drop=True)
    ...: test
    ...: 
    ...: 
Out[20]: 
    drink        day  cups  day_norm  normalized cups
0     tea     monday     1  0.111111            1.000
1     tea    tuesday     3  0.750000            3.000
2     tea  wednesday     1  0.333333            1.000
3     tea   thursday     7  0.875000            7.000
4     tea     friday     1  0.500000            1.000
5  coffee     monday     8  0.888889            1.000
6  coffee    tuesday     1  0.250000            0.125
7  coffee  wednesday     2  0.666667            0.250
8  coffee   thursday     1  0.125000            0.125
9  coffee     friday     1  0.500000            0.125
```

but that involves a lot of messing about with the index in order to get them to match those of the original dataframe.

Two: I can reshape the data into a wide format table:

```py
n [14]: summary = test.drop(columns=['normalized cups']).groupby(['drink', 'day'])['cups'].mean().unstack()

In [15]: summary
Out[15]: 
day     friday  monday  thursday  tuesday  wednesday
drink                                               
coffee       8       7         7        8          4
tea          9       9         4        8          4
```

and then the division becomes more simple, but I have to spend a bit of time getting it back to the original format:

```py
In [16]: summary.apply(lambda x : x / summary['monday']).stack().to_frame('norma
    ...: lized_cups').reset_index()
Out[16]: 
    drink        day  normalized_cups
0  coffee     friday         1.142857
1  coffee     monday         1.000000
2  coffee   thursday         1.000000
3  coffee    tuesday         1.142857
4  coffee  wednesday         0.571429
5     tea     friday         1.000000
6     tea     monday         1.000000
7     tea   thursday         0.444444
8     tea    tuesday         0.888889
9     tea  wednesday         0.444444
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I have a vague idea of sorting the dataframe so that monday is first, then doing something involving `groupby` and `first`, but I can't quite think of it!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I will do

```
t2=test.loc[test.day=='monday',['drink','cups']].groupby('drink').cups.mean()
t2
Out[1282]:
drink
coffee    8
tea       1
Name: cups, dtype: int64
test['normalized_cups']=test.cups/t2.reindex(test.drink).values
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion; I always forget about the power of `reindex` to broadcast stuff to multiple rows like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['normalized_cups'] = df.groupby('drink').cups.apply(lambda x: x/x.iloc[0])
```

this assumes you have `monday` first in each group.

Comment: @Wen-Ben thanks, I did overlook that as OP said *over the week*, so let see. In that case, sounds like OP wants all monday to be 1. Then, something like your answer, but `cumsum()` instead of `mean()` works.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was thinking with my idea of taking the first. In the real-life cases I'm thinking of we generally do have only monday per group, so this will work great.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you separate data collection & storage from data analysis.
For example, you could record each drink in a table when you drink it.
Then you could run the analysis at any time.

The data table would look something like this:
[image]

You could also add a separate "person" table and have a "caffeine count competition" with your friends.