# pandas seaborn pointplot normalized by control group mean

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I am struggling to find a solution to normalize a grouped seaborn pointplot of a pandas dataframe ***by the mean of a control group***

to try to be more clear this is the result of my seaborn plot
[image],
as a result of this code:

```
sns.pointplot(x='CELL TYPE',y='VELOCITY', hue = 'condition',ci=99 ,data=df_condition_cut1,ax = ax,order=['FRONT', 'MIDDLE', 'BACK'],
                               ordered=True)
```

what I want to obtain is this kind of plot but normalized by the mean of the FRONT cell type within each condition.

**Please find here a sampled significant dataset with a simplified plot**

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df_cells = pd.DataFrame(data = {'VELOCITY':[1.4,1.6,1.3,1.1,0.8,0.7,2.3,1.8,1.7,1.5,1.6,1.7],
                         'condition':['A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A2','A2','A2'],
                         'CELL TYPE':['FRONT','FRONT','MIDDLE','MIDDLE','BACK','BACK','FRONT','FRONT','MIDDLE','MIDDLE','BACK','BACK']})
print(df_cells)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,12))
sns.pointplot(x='CELL TYPE',y='VELOCITY', hue = 'condition',ci=99 ,data=df_cells,ax = ax,order=['FRONT', 'MIDDLE', 'BACK'],
                                   ordered=True)
```

[image: sampled dataset]

Do you have any suggestions about how to obtain this?

thanks
Emanuele

Comment: Please, can you provide a significant sample of your data?

Comment: dear @Zephyr, 
I've updated my post with a sampled data and a little snipped to plot it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55971778/15416347

I've found a solution.

In my particular case this code works:

```py
t2=df_cells.loc[df_cells['CELL TYPE']=='FRONT',['VELOCITY','CELL TYPE','condition']].groupby('condition').VELOCITY.mean()
df_cells['VELOCITY_norm']=df_cells.VELOCITY/t2.reindex(df_cells.condition).values

df_cells.VELOCITY_norm
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,12))
sns.pointplot(x='CELL TYPE',y='VELOCITY_norm', hue = 'condition',ci=99 ,data=df_cells,ax = ax,order=['FRONT', 'MIDDLE', 'BACK'],
                                   ordered=True)
```

[image: normalized]